# Getting urls without hashes in Ember.js on Github Pages

Tags: ember.js, ember-app-kit

I wanted to get rid of ugly hash tags in my url (www.example.com/#/projects/id -> www.example.com/projects/id). So I added

```
Router.reopen({
    location: 'history'
});
```

This works if I open my app to the root www.example.com, and click on a link-to I can visit www.example.com/projects and so on. However, if I put www.example.com/projects in my url bar and load the page that way, we get a 404 error. It makes sense to me why that would happen (after all, the server is only serving the javascript assets on the one url). I'm using github pages for my site, what approach should I use to make this work?

Comment: Youd need to setup a redirect in your htaccess file for something like that which I dont believe Github Pages supports.

Answer (score 3):

Basically your server needs to serve your index.html file no matter what url is entered.

> Keep in mind that your server must serve the Ember app at all the routes defined here.

More in [the docs](http://emberjs.com/guides/routing/specifying-the-location-api/)